# How do I find out what the Date is for Next Saturday or the current Saturday?

Tags: vba, excel, date

I am writing some VBA for Excel and I need to figure out the date for the current or upcoming Saturday

So if it's Friday, I need to get tomorrow's date (Saturday).

If today is Saturday then I just want today's date.

If it's Sunday then I need yesterday's date.

If it's Monday then next Saturday

I was wondering if there was anything in Excel or VBA that can help me accomplish this

Comment: Maybe this helps https://superuser.com/questions/376698/how-to-get-the-dates-of-the-current-monday-wednesday-and-friday-of-the-current

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something easy to understand, using `vbDays` variables and `Select Case`.

In general, you have 3 cases - today is Saturday, Sunday or Else. These are presented in the Select Case.

The function is date, thus in Excel it would be formated as the standard date result.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function SaturdayIsComing() As Date

    Select Case Weekday(Now)

        Case vbSaturday
        SaturdayIsComing = Now

        Case vbSunday
        SaturdayIsComing = DateAdd("d", -1, Now)

        Case Else
        SaturdayIsComing = DateAdd("d", vbSaturday - Weekday(Now), Now)

    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: This has a chance to return a wrong value if called very close to midnight.

Answer (score 5):

In Excel you can use this formula:

```
=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY())>1, 7, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't just using excel and need it for other `vba` projects, this gives the result you desire.

```
Private Function saturdayFunction()
    Dim dt As String
    Dim lpDT As String

    lpDT = Format(Now, "yyyy/MM/dd")

    If Format(Now, "DDDD") = "Saturday" Then
        dt = Format(Now, "yyyy/MM/dd")
    ElseIf Format(Now, "DDDD") = "Sunday" Then
        dt = Format(Now - 1, "yyyy/MM/dd")
    Else
        Do While Not dt = "Saturday"
            dt = Format(CDate(lpDT) + 1, "DDDD")
            lpDT = Format(CDate(lpDT) + 1, "yyyy/MM/dd")
        Loop

        dt = lpDT
    End If

    saturdayFunction = dt
End Function
```

Comment: Wonderful, a downvote with no explanation for working code.

Comment: "Working code" and "code that happens to give correct result on one machine" are very different things. This code is fundamentally broken and will only work on the `en-us` locale. It is also very wrong in its approach because it stores all dates as strings and uses a loop where there is no need for one.

Comment: @GSerg a lot of your points are more suited for https:/codereview.stackexchange.com which is not where this is posted. OP never stated locale. Given the language of the site and a bulk of the questions I've seen being `en-us` formatting. I see nothing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Make Format Cells into "Date"

```
=TODAY()+6-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)
```