# Excel VBA set date to nearest day, is there a better way to do it?

Tags: excel, vba

Recently I needed to set some dates in Excel to the nearest Wednesday for a scheduling process.
I found some answers here in stackoverflow and other sites but none were giving the desired result at all times. So, I wrote a little sub to achieve this for any day you need, but it got me wondering if there was a better way to achieve this, if not then I hope you find it helpful.

***EDIT:*** This sub is part of a large process run by a macro by clicking a custom ribbon button, the input dates come from an array, therefore, I have to use vba to change them.

Here is the matrix with results:

[image]

And the code is this:

```
Sub SetNextWed()

    Range("A6").Activate
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
        SetToNextDate ActiveCell.Value, vbWednesday, 2
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Loop
End Sub

Sub SetToNextDate(MyDate As Date, DayOfWeek As Integer, Column As Integer)
    Dim dNext_Wednesday As Date

    dNext_Wednesday = MyDate

    Select Case Weekday(MyDate)
        Case DayOfWeek
            dNext_Wednesday = MyDate
        Case Else
            dNext_Wednesday = MyDate + DayOfWeek - Weekday(MyDate)
            If MyDate > dNext_Wednesday Then
                dNext_Wednesday = MyDate + ((DayOfWeek + 7) - Weekday(MyDate))
            End If
    End Select
```

I've tried this solutions:

https://vbaf1.com/date-time/next-wednesday-date/
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/determine-date-of-next-and-most-recent-monday-vba.983467/
[How do I find out what the Date is for Next Saturday or the current Saturday?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484129/how-do-i-find-out-what-the-date-is-for-next-saturday-or-the-current-saturday)

Comment: A better approach would be to make it a `Function` that _returns_ the next Wednesday instead of mutating its inputs. Also there's probably an enum type you could use instead of an `Integer` for the `DayOfWeek` parameter; a `Function` could be invoked directly from worksheet cells.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I see what you mean by using a function in a Cell, but my input data comes from an array, have to get the result before adding data to the cells. But the enum type... I'm interested in knowing more of that.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, dates are just numbers, and the date number modulo 7 gives you the day of the week, with 0 as Saturday through 6 as Friday.  So you don't need VBA.  The following cell formula calculates the Wednesday date you desire: `=7*INT((A1+2)/7)+4`, assuming the original date is in A1.

[image]

Comment: This is a nice one liner, I'll try to do the same in vba, as the data I get comes from an array in a macro and have to show the result dates already modified.

Comment: OK, seems to work just fine, I'll try editing this answer with the code later, as right now queue is full. Thanks man!